# Effect as seen on BlackNegative

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was wondering on how to do the effect as seen on [Black Negative](http://www.blacknegative.com/#!/whoweare/) - Im talking about the hover effekt there is on the text "Telling, Fascinating, Stories"...
Can you do it with only css3, or jQuery, if so, how?

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the basic functionality using jQuery (definitely not perfect, but you could make it work with a bit of tweaking):

```
/* Expand on mouseover */
$(".whoweare-title").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: '87px',
        marginTop: '27px',
        marginBottom: '27px'
    });
    $(".whoweare-section-container").stop(true, false).animate({
        marginTop: '-126px',
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: '24px',
        marginTop: '0px',
        marginBottom: '0px'
    });
    $(".whoweare-section-container").stop(true, false).animate({
        marginTop: '-67px',
    });
});
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwoidke/qUeBq).

Comment: Hmm, not quite the same - The text is moving in this example - Im tried doing exactly the same with CSS3 and transitions, i get the same result, where the text is moving :(

Comment: I think the problem is that the `whoweare-section-container` is not sliding up. If it were, the text would appear to stay still. I might have the code wrong though; I wrote it pretty quickly in the fiddle.